# go run app.go always run in the background

Tags: go

I have a simple HTTP server, and I want to run it as a process in the background.

my server.go file is like:

```golang
package main
    
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)
    
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there X, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
    
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

And I run: `go run server.go`

VS Code Launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "debug",
      "remotePath": "",
      "port": 2345,
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "env": {},
      "args": [],
      "showLog": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Update: I get this error in VS Code Terminal:

```
2017/04/07 16:41:41 debugger.go:257: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:1, Name:"", Addr:0x12063ef, File:"/Users/X/Documents/X/play/go/server.go", Line:9, FunctionName:"main.handler", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/04/07 16:41:41 debugger.go:412: continuing
```

Comment: There's no way for a go program to just "run in the background". You have to do that yourself.

Comment: Strange that it does. I think it is a bug in VS Code and dlv.

Comment: No, I guarantee it does not, a Go program is multithreaded and cannot fork itself. More likely it's exiting immediately, have you checked the error returned from `http.ListenAndServe`?

Comment: Thanks - I have updated with what VS Code is writing in the Terminal.

Comment: OK, but you're still not checking the error from `ListenAndServe`. Are you certain that the process is continuing to run?  What file is `server.js` referring to? Shouldn't "program" in the launch config point to your program, not "workspaceRoot"?

Comment: You got it, and I am sure I have tried that many times - that is setting: "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server.go", Well, now the debugger stops at breakpoints and no more killing processes. Well thanks

Comment: Also, you can check out Gogland. I used both Gogland and VS Code, and found it more easy to use for go

Comment: You can use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you tried running your server using [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)?

```
nohup go run server.go &
```

Comment: how to stop server.go?